# Is there a way to detect where exactly button was pressed in Xamarin Android application in C#

Tags: xml, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to detect where on the ImageButton tap is made. I need to get a value (e.g. coordinates of offset from center).

Can I do it just with a button or do I need to use something else?

[Here is the button that I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMfSu.png)

Comment: @ewerspej he is asking about Android specifically, not Forms

Comment: @Jason oh right, I missed that part apparently.